# How to show/hide selected object like div?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

So i'm trying out MVC after only playing with it some time ago.

Need to find the best way to selectively show and hide sections (divs, etc) on clicking or changing a value of a control, but not having to post back, i.e. javascript?

Any suggestions.

Comment: Bad question. Please update your question & tag. Question may be "How to show/hide selected object like div?". Tag could be javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). You can use a jQuery Event to detect a click and then [hide](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/hide) or [show](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/show) divs.

So, You have a button called "HideDiv" and "DivToHide" is the div you wish to hide.

```
$("#HideDiv").click(function() {
   $("#divToHide").hide();
};
```

It's that easy. Can't really go in-depth here but check out their tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials or browse this site: http://www.learningjquery.com/category/levels/beginner

jQuery actually comes with ASP.Net MVC, check the scripts folder of a new MVC project and you'll see it in there. This site using jQuery and MVC :) So your browsing a sample of what is possible with it

Comment: Where's the best quickstart resource for jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same way as you are doing it with normal ASP.NET application using JavaScript. I think JavaScript is best as its fast and works on client-side.

If you are having a specific requirement then please put the specific requirement here.
You can use jQuery or MooTools if you want some animation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery. It is included with the standard MVC project template.

```
$("#myButtonId").click(function () {
  $("#myDivId").toggle();
});
```

See more at the jQuery docs for [toggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle).